# Default arguments using mocked objects

Tags: mocking, python-sphinx, autodoc, default-arguments

I am using Sphinx v1.8.5 to build documentation for Python 2 code that has external dependencies that I mock using `autodoc_mock_imports`. I get an error message when I try to use the mocked object (`RAMP`) as a default argument:

```py
def foo(name, amp=RAMP):
```

The error says:

> NameError: name 'RAMP' is not defined

If I do not use `RAMP` as a default argument, the error disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question and explicitly include the code where you are defining the mock. Also show an example how RAMP is imported and any other uses of it in the module. Is the default value in the argument the only place where an error occurs?

Comment: Yep, RAMP is defined in the module `step`, which is imported without `from step import *`, but regular `import step`. So setting `step.RAMP` as the default value resolves the issue. Should have been more attentive. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You should self-accept the answer to indicate the problem was solved. It's important to signal for members searching questions to know if they are solved or not.

Comment: Thanks. I can only do it after 2 days, 7 hours to go :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to the comment of @bad_coder I realised that the hurdle was stemming from how the modules were imported. I needed to resolve the scope with `module_defining_RAMP.RAMP` instead of directly accessing `RAMP`.

Of course, then I got the ugly value of the mocked object in the output of my documentation:

> foo(name, amp=<sphinx.ext.autodoc.importer._MockObject object>)

but I have already seen the solution to this problem while searching for my own. I needed to simply state the function signature in the doc string:

```
def foo(name, amp=RAMP):
"""
foo(name, amp=module_defining_RAMP.RAMP)
"""
```